# What difference does usage of symbol @ with ini_set, built-in function makes in PHP?

Tags: php, settings, php-ini, ini-set

In one of my project's configuration settings I observed following two lines at the beginning of file :

```
@ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
@set_time_limit(0);
```

My doubt is what's the difference in the above two lines of code and following lines of code?

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
set_time_limit(0);
```

What's the intention of prefixing @ symbol in PHP?

Please provide me in detail and to the point answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uhm, I didn't know those functions needed an error suppressor?

Comment: @DamienPirsy They do when you try to set a value when you are using PHP in safe mode or when the functions are disabled.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Nice, I didn't know that, I thought they were quite universally appliable

Comment: @DamienPirsy It is in the documentation. Try running that code on http://writecodeonline.com/php and you will see the warnings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

@ in php is simply for silencing errors.

for example:

```
<?php
    $x = 5;
    $y = @$z;
```

so $y will be null

if you remove the @
it will throw an error.

Comment: You forgot to mention that the `error_reporting` value in `php.ini` must have the 'bit-flag' `E_WARNING` (value `2`) on it's value. For example, the value `E_ALL`. Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php for more about this.

Comment: thanks for the comment, now others will see it as well.

Answer (score 3):

**Error Control Operators**

PHP supports one error control operator: the at sign (@). When prepended to an expression in PHP, any error messages that might be generated by that expression will be ignored.

[Error Control Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)